# Loading textures using TextureLoader from Resources

Tags: c#, directx, textures

I'd like to ask how could I load textures from program resources.

This code works fine, but its only from file. How about loading from resources?

```
texture = TextureLoader.FromFile(device, "file.png");
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found solution.

```
texture = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.image);
```

Did the trick. :)

Comment: Please post the solution so others that are looking for the same thing can be helped.  Thanks!